# Perform a mathematical function on a JOIN of 2 tables - each with a COUNT function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to accomplish the following-

I have 2 tables for soccer teams (not created by me, this is what I have to work with):

```
won_matches-
columns: team_id | match_name | scored_goals

lost_matches-
columns: team_id | match_name | scored_goals

teams_names-
team_id | team_name
```

(I don't care about the match name or the number of scored goals)

What I need to do is COUNT how many entries each team has in the won_matches table and how many entries it has in the lost_matches table, and then divide the number of lost_matches by the number of won_matches, thus getting a lost/won matches ratio.
I then need to present this ratio for each team (or all teams) along with its team name.

I tried somethings like this, but it doesn't work as needed:

```
SELECT b. team_name, (SELECT COUNT(team_id)
FROM won_matches [***optional; WHERE team_id=37***]) / COUNT(a.team_id)*100 AS lost_won_ratio
FROM lost_matches a 
join teams_names b on a.team_id=b.team_id
[***optional; WHERE a.team_id=37***]
```

Would be grateful for your suggestions.

Comment: You need to learn about JOIN operations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29, the syntax in particular...

Comment: Consider working your way up to a position of authority, firing everyone responsible for this design, and then restructuring to obviate the need for the UNION

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select team_id, Won, count(*) as Matches, sum(scored_goals) as Goals
from 
(select 1 as Won, Team_id, scored_goals from won_matches
union all
select 0 as Won, team_id, scored_goals from lost_matches) x
group by team_id, Won
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that will do the trick:

```
select team_id,
       count(won), count(lost),
       count(won)/(count(won)+count(lost)) as 'Win ratio' from
(
select True as won, NULL as lost, won_matches.* from won_matches
union all
select NULL as won, True as lost, lost_matches.* from lost_matches
) as S group by team_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dbaf/2 (EDIT: use a join to display team name)

Please notice I don't take into account possible drawn matches since I don't know how this is stored in your DB.

**EDIT** Notice as well I used `count(won)/(count(won)+count(lost))` as count ratio formula. That seems more logical. If you stick with `count(lost)/count(win)` you will have to deal with the divide by 0 case...

Comment: Sylvian, this seems to work for me.
One question though, as far as I know union can only handle two quesries, so how would you add a join with the teams_names table as well? (to show the team name along with its ID in the results)

Comment: I ran yet into another problem, forgot to mention that my 2 tables for union have different number of columns... so I assume union will not work.

I'm thinking about using temp tables which will only have the relevant columns.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: @Rani two comments: (1) for simplicity here I used the `.*` notation meaning *all columns*. Maybe both table have the same number of *required* columns? (2) Since this is a different topic, you should check if it has already been answered, and if not, post an new question "How to perform union of two tables with differents number of columns"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT tn.teamID, sum(won_matches.teamID ) as WON, sum(lost_matches.teamID ) as LOST,(sum(won_matches.teamID )/sum(lost_matches.teamID )) as WLratio
From teams_names AS tn LEFT JOIN won_matches ON tn.teamID = won_matches.teamID LEFT JOIN lost_matches ON tn.teamID = lost_matches.teamID
```

Comment: Only issues here would be 1/0 or 0/1. Wherein you could use a case statement